# Qt C++ write to / read from "IBM037 / CP037"

Tags: c++, qt, encoding, character-encoding

I was looking for a way to write to and read from IBM037 encoding in Qt. I was able to achieve that in C# by using

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM037")
```

However, I am currently porting an application from C# to C++ using Qt, and I wasn't able to find a way to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am aware of QTextCodec but it does not contain a definition for IBM 037. Using it returns a normal text (non-encoded).

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html (which is 2nd hit on Google for "Qt text encoding", so you didn't look very hard).

Comment: It does not contain a definition for IBM037, it only has IBM 850, IBM 866, and IBM 874.

Comment: You should add researched information like that to the question here, it's just a good idea :)

Comment: Edited the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own class derived from QTextCodec and use tables (like the ones available [here](http://people.cs.umu.se/isak/Snippets/a2e.c) ) to perform the translation character by character. 
As suggested in the comments, check what stated in the QTextCodec documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#creating-your-own-codec-class).

With tables like these you can translate to ASCII 8 bit. Then convert the ASCII characters to Unicode using the functions already provided by the Qt framework.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to C++ coming from higher level languages, but it seems that your solution is still possible. I'll try and show my findings later.

Comment: @MustafaAlAmeen QTextCodec docs describe briferly how to subclass it to add support for new codecs.